# Toggle button state via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two buttons like (thumbs up) and unlike (thumbs down). Clicking on one button should toggle the state of both, only one being active.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
<button type="button" class="bout unlike bthumb boutontagthumbdown" id="unlike_'.$row['tag_number_id'].'" value="unlike">
    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down fa-lg"></i>
</button>'
<button type="button" class="bout like bthumb boutontagthumbup" id="like_'.$row['tag_number_id'].'" value="like">
    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-lg"></i>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        console.log( "ready!" );

        $(".bout").click(function(){
            var Id = this.id;
            var Idunlike = ("#" + Id + ".bout.unlike");
            var Idlike = ("#" + Id + ".bout.like");

            if ( $(this).attr("value") == 'unlike' ){
                $(Idunlike).toggleClass("boutontagthumbdownclic");
                $(Idlike).addClass("boutontagthumbupclicreturn");
                console.log(Idunlike);
            } else if ( $(this).attr("value") == 'like' ) {
                $(Idlike).toggleClass("boutontagthumbupclic");
                $(Idunlike).addClass("boutontagthumbdownclicreturn");
                console.log(Idlike);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There're too many orthographic errors in your question in order to be able to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$(function(){ 
 
 $(".bout").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];  
  switch($(this).attr('value')){
   case 'like' :
    $('#like_'+id).addClass('boutontagthumbupclic').removeClass('boutontagthumbupclicreturn');
    $('#unlike_'+id).addClass('boutontagthumbdownclicreturn').removeClass('boutontagthumbdownclic');
   break;
   case 'unlike' :
    $('#like_'+id).addClass('boutontagthumbupclicreturn').removeClass('boutontagthumbupclic');
    $('#unlike_'+id).addClass('boutontagthumbdownclic').removeClass('boutontagthumbdownclicreturn');
   break;
  }
 }); 
 
});
```

```css
.boutontagthumbupclic{color:green;}
.boutontagthumbdownclic{color:red;}

.boutontagthumbdownclicreturn,
.boutontagthumbupclicreturn{color:#555;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button type="button" class="bout unlike bthumb boutontagthumbdown" id="unlike_1" value="unlike"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-lg"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="bout like bthumb boutontagthumbup" id="like_1" value="like"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer is perfect...Thank you...A+++

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```js
$(function(){    
    $(".status button").click(function () {
        $(".status").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="status">
    <button type="button" class="like" value="like">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-lg"></i>
    </button>'
    <button type="button" class="unlike" value="like">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down fa-lg"></i>
    </button>'
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.like i, .unlike i {
    color: gray
}
.like.active i {   
    color: green;
}
.unlike.active i {
    color: red;
}
```